# Prove that {$a ∈ ℤ : a ≤ k$} has a greatest element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that the set {$a ∈ ℤ : a ≤ k$}, where $k∈ℝ$, has a greatest element?

I have tried using the Well-ordering theorem in order to get a contradiction but I'm having trouble with my approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Just saying - intuitively, the result is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is an integer, there is nothing to prove. So we can assume that $k$ is not an integer.

Call an integer $m$ **good** if $m-k\ge 0$. There are good integers, by the Archimedean property of the reals, which we assume has already been proved.

All good integers are $\ge k$, so the set of good integers is bounded below.

It follows that there is a **smallest** good integer $g$.   Since $k$ is not an integer, we cannot have $g=k$. Now consider $g-1$. This number is not good, so $g-1\lt k$, and it is the largest integer which is $\lt k$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The floor function: $\lfloor k \rfloor$. For example, if $k$ were $2.1$, then the greatest element of your set would be $2$.